# Non-HTML5 audio playing on page load, launch function when it's finished

Tags: jquery, audio, internet-explorer-8

I've tried to look this answer up but it all seems to be html5 based.  I need an audio file to play on page load and then when it finishes to launch a function.  It needs to be compatible with IE 8 and preferably using jQuery.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think you will fall back on plugins like Windows Media Player or Flash.

Comment: can you use flash and have a jquery function fire when the audio finishes?

Comment: Yes you can. If you build the Flash like that, or find one that has that functionality.